# Visual Studio Solution Explorer Position

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Does anyone know if there is a way to always make a certain tab appear at the top? I’d like to have solution explorer there.

I know I can pin and unpin until things get how I want them, but that can get messed-up with further pinning and unpinning.

[image]

Comment: If I understood, you could do this: 1) Move Solution explorer to the top (drag and drop) 2) Select "Auto Hide" property. In VS2012 that will put "Solution Explorer" above the code tabs. VS will remember that configuration the next time.

Comment: @Pabloker Well, you can't drag the tabs, but you can change the positions by pinning and unpinning. Even though VS will remember it next time, it doesn't survive further pinning and unpinning.

Comment: Well I tried this: 1) `Tools/Options/Envirenment/Tabs and Windows`. I checked the three `Pinned Tabs` options. 2) Pinned some tabs. 3) Saved the project and closed VS. When I re-opened VS, my pinned tabs were there.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that they'll get messed-up again if you pin and unpin Solution Explorer. It will go back to the bottom. That's what I'm trying to prevent from happening.

Comment: Yes, this is very annoying...especially when working on multiple machines and instances of VS. You should be able to drag/drop the tabs to maintain "your order". I sent them a "Frown" via the Feedback feature in VS2013 and referenced this page.

Answer (score 6):

1. Pin Solution Explorer
2. For each remaining tab: Pin it then drag it into the Solution Explorer tab so that it appears as a tab at the bottom of Solution Explorer.
3. Order the tabs as you require at the bottom of Solution Explorer.
4. Unpin and your tab order should be as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a solution:

1. Arrange your Tabs as you like
2. Export your Settings through => Menu/ Tools / Settings Import and Export

After that is done you can always re-import the settings which will also reset the Window Layout with the given Settings.
Also you can use the Function "Reset Window Layout" (Menu/Window)

Does work on VS 2008 - 2012. And should work on 2013 too.